# cannot use public var vba

Tags: vba, public, var

i am wrting a vba code where i will set some public var to use in many subs
vars declared in userform code like this

```
public xxxx as string

sub vars()
xxxx = "test"
end sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' test button 
MsgBox ("pub var is " & xxxx)
End Sub
```

when i click in test buton the msg box is blank looks like it cant see the pub var
aney ideas where is the problem
(even if i set public xxxx as srtring in the code of a module or thisworkbook i get the same result)
thanks

Comment: What is probably happening is, you run the `vars` sub and it saves `"test"` to `xxxx`, then the script stops running.  Once the script stops, all your variables disappear - nothing is saved.  You would need to call `vars` within the `CommandButton1_Click` sub - if you really need to save a value between runs of the script, either save it in a cell (if using excel) or in a table (in Access).

Comment: 1. Where did you call subroutine 'vars'? 2. where is xxxx defined? your code will work if you define properly, set the value, then reference.

Comment: thanks for the comments. @Acantud yes i need to call xxxx each time i need it (i am using excel and xxxx will define the last empty row in a column and i will use this var in many place so i dont wont to declare it each time i'll use).

Comment: @Wayne G.Dunn : subroutine vars is coded in main userform code and xxxx is defined on the same place just inside vars sub and just in the begining of userform code i declared a public xxxx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks obvious to me, so I may have misunderstood the question.

You're not calling `vars()` anywhere, so the string `xxxx` is initialised to its default value (blank). If you change your code to call `vars()` as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  ' call vars() to set the string value
  vars

  ' test button
  MsgBox ("pub var is " & xxxx)
End Sub
```

then it will work as you expect.

In my test, even if I call `vars()` first on its own and then your button_click as you posted it, the value of `xxxx` is set correctly. Obviously, this value won't survive closing Excel and restarting it. In that case, you'll need to save its value externally somewhere and reload it when Excel is restarted.

Comment: thanks i will use this method, call the sub vars in each subroutine where i need xxxx var.